# update_user_meta / get_user_meta out of sync when called in the same ajax function

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, metadata

I'm trying to save and retrieve metadata - working on a wordpress project.

I have a bizarre issue when calling get_user_meta. Can anyone explain why? It's as if update_user_meta and get_user_meta are not sequential functions.

I'm calling update_user_meta first to update the value.
Next I'm calling get_user_meta to retrieve the value. (doing so for testing purpose, I realize this might look a little weird :) The point is - however - these update / get calls are made in the same ajax request.

The filter executes - calling it is not an issue.

Problem is - there is a 50% chance get_user_meta will get the old meta value, not the one I just updated.

```
public function addcampaign_getlist($sponsorlist, $downloadid) {

    update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'testvar', $downloadid);

    $sponsorlist['download_id'] = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'testvar', true ); 
    return $sponsorlist;
}

add_filter('sfc_add_campaign_get_list', array($this, 'addcampaign_getlist'), 10, 2);
```

The filter is called through ajax, as below. I know the call works, because after I refresh, subsequent get_user_meta calls do retrieve the correct data.
But there seems to be a sequentiality issue between update_user_meta and get_user_meta if executed in the same ajax function.

```
function sfc_ajax_add_to_support() {
    $sponsorlist=   array( 'download_id' => 0 );
    if ( isset( $_POST['download_id'] ) ) 
        $sponsorlist = apply_filters('sfc_add_campaign_get_list', $sponsorlist,$_POST['download_id'] );
    echo json_encode( $sponsorlist );   
    edd_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_sfc_add_to_support', 'sfc_ajax_add_to_support' );
```

What I'm trying to achieve is display a list of values, by user ID, that I can add to or remove from.

The only solution I can think of is define and update the list as a class instead of trying to update the database directly. Any other suggestions?

Thank you,

Comment: You don't have to use `get_user_meta`. you can just update the list with js, and when he refresh the page the results return from the `get_user_mete` will stay the same as the js that you update. its will save you call to the DB as well.

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right. I'll do that.